# Place a null value after a string after being read from a file in C?

Tags: c, string, file-io

How would one append a null character at the end of a string read in from a file that has different sized strings on each line ... something like this:

AAAAA    BBBBB

AAAA    BBBBBBB

AAAAA    BBBBB

I'd only want to read the first string on each line. I'd like to put this into a string. However, C does not put nulls at the end of strings, you have to do it yourself. How can I get a null character at the end of the string while using fscanf...is that possible? Do I need to use another function to read in the file instead of fscanf?

Sorry for the simple problem. I just can't find the answer anywhere...

Comment: Have you tried it? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Yes. I tried doing a strcat to the string i read in to tack on a null but I get errors.

Comment: Probably another error, as Mikel says its being added already.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want a null at the end of each line?

The Linux `fscanf` documentation says the null is added automatically if you are using `%s`.

> ```
>    s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters;
>             the next pointer must be a pointer to character array
>             that is long enough to hold the input sequence and
>             the terminating  null  character ('\0'), which is
>             added automatically.
> ```

Or do you mean you want a null everywhere there is a space in the input file?

`strtok` would be one way to achieve that.

Comment: This worked. I don't know why it was erroring before...probably something stupid I did. e.e; THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Note that `"%s"` does _not_ read a line from a file, nor (IMHO) should `scanf` or `fscanf` ever be used (or needed).

Comment: Yeah, IIRC `getline` should be used.

Comment: I always use fscanf to read liens because it is a standard ANSI function. One just have to define delimiters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a buffer of characters of whatever size your maximum line length is. Use the fgets() function to read each line into the buffer... fgets() will null terminate the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard-lib str-functions for building strings. They will ever put a terminating '\0'.

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
char line[MAXLINE], yourstring[MAXLINE];
while( fgets(line,MAXLINE,yourfilepointer) )
{
  sscanf(line,"%s",yourstring); /* here has yourstring ever a terminating '\0' */
  printf("first word is: %s\n",yourstring);
}
```

Comment: fgets() itself appends a NULL... the sscanf() is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Create two buffers:

```
char buf1[1000], buf2[1000];
```

Use this to read the first word on a line:

```
fscanf(f,"%s", buf1);
```

Then use this to read the rest of a line:

```
fscanf(f,"%[^\n\r]s", buf2);
```

Now you have the first word in `buf1` and the rest of the line in `buf2`.